# how to extand two header file in same template before login other and after login another header file

Tags: django, django-templates

**how to extand two header file in same template before login other and after login another header file**

```
{% if not request.user.is_authenticated %}
   {% extends 'portal/v1/base-template.html' %}
{% else %}
   {% extends 'portal/v1/auth/base-template.html' %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Maybe you can add why current code is not running for you as expected. What are the roadblocks?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can send the header file name from view and render in template accordingly.

In views.py

```
if request.user.is_authenticated:
    base_template = 'portal/v1/auth/base-template.html'
else:
    base_template = 'portal/v1/base-template.html'

context = {
         'base_template': base_template,
        }
```

In html

```
  {% extends base_template %}
```